# What is this modulo 11 check digit algorithm called?

Tags: coding-theory

Can you help me identify the name of the algorithm described here that calculates the check digit of a $10-$digit number?

Given a $012\text-345678\text-n$ arrangement of separated digits, where **n** is the check digit, the following algorithm is used to calculate the check digit:

1. Ignoring the $n$ digit, for each next digit take the **value** of the digit and multiply it by the **position** of the digit from right-to-left, where $n$ is the $1^{st}$ digit in this example, and $0$ is the $10^{th}$ digit.
2. Calculate the **sum** of each multiplication from step $1$, and then **modulo** the result by $11$.
3. If the result is **less than $2$**, it should be **equal** to the check digit ($n$). Otherwise, the sum of $n$ and the calculated result should be **equal to $11$**.

As an example, the step $1$ results in:
$$0\cdot10 + 1\cdot9 + 2\cdot8 + 3\cdot7 + 4\cdot6 + 5\cdot5 + 6\cdot4 + 7\cdot3 + 8\cdot2 = 156$$
(notice that the last digit ($8$) is in the $2^{nd}$ position from right to left)

In step $2$, the sum ($156$) modulo $11$ would be $2$.

In step $3$, the result $2$ is *not less than $2$*, so the check digit ($n$) plus $2$ should be equal to $11$, which means that $n = 11 - 2 = 9$.

Thus, $012\text-345678\text-9$ would be a valid series of digits with this algorithm.

---

This algorithm is used for national ID verification in Iran, and I have [written](https://gist.github.com/DRSDavidSoft/4cd1ede79656a91746bc1806cdee0675) an example implementation, but I don't know what the algorithm is called.

```
/**
 * Example Javascript snippet to validate Iran's National ID (Code Melli)
 * https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740295/285467
 * David Refoua <David@Refoua.me>
 */
function validateNID( code )
{
    var str = code.toString();

    // validate the string length and value
    var strLen = str.length, strVal = parseInt(str);
    if ( strLen < 8 || strLen > 10 || isNaN(strVal) || strVal == 0 )
        return false;

    // make sure the string is padded with zeros
    while ( str.length < 10 ) str = '0' + str;

    // invalidate consecutive arrangement of the same digit
    if ( str.match(/^(\d)\1+$/g) ) return false;

    var checkDigit = parseInt(str.slice(-1)), // rightmost digit
        str = str.slice(0, -1); // remove the check digit

    for ( var sum = 0, i = str.length; i > 0; i-- )
        sum += (i+1) * str.substr( -i, 1 );

    // calculate sum modulo 11
    var mod = sum % 11;

    return ( mod < 2 && mod === checkDigit ) || ( mod >= 2 && mod + checkDigit === 11);

}
```

I'm not sure whether the same algorithm also used in ISBN-10, or if it's a different but similar one. Originally I thought it was an extension of the Luhn Algorithm, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Could you help me identify its name?

Comment: It seems to match [ISBN-10](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ISBN.html) (Equation 1) where $1$ is used in place of X.